# How to keep up-to-date between RN and Native Android Screen about current stack?

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, react-native-router-flux

I'm triggering android activity `FullScreenActivity` whenever video notification comes into the app. This screen display on top of react-native. But I don't want to trigger this `FullScreenActivity` when user is on a specific screen of react-native.

we have same feature coded on RN and android. I want to achieve

- when app is foreground and not in RN specific screen, FullScreenActivity should trigger.
- when app is foreground and in RN specific screen, FullScreenActivity should not trigger and call RN scene instead.
- when app is background or killed, FullScreenActivity should trigger.

Scenario:

1. user is in screen 1 -> got notification -> now trigger FullScreenActivity.
2. How to handle if user moves to screen 2 (doesn't trigger if in screen 2) while the above step in progress?

How android know user in the `specific screen of RN` and how RN should know `FullScreenActivity` is currently active? I want to make one / two-way communication between both platforms.

Comment: Do you have experience with native modules?

Comment: Yeah.  I have exposed a few RCTMethods and UIViewManagers. But not have much about android activity and lifecycle stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make two-way communication between platforms. I assume you know how to create and register your native modules in Android.

React-Native -> Android communication.

Native code:

```java
@ReactMethod
public void setCurrentScreen(String screen) {
}
```

In JS code, you can attach navigation listener to your Router via setting `onStateChange` prop and calling `YourNativeModule.setCurrentScreen()` method.

Android -> React-Native communication:

Just send an event from FullScreenActivity to JS with activity state information and subscribe to events in JS.

```kotlin
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        sendActivityStartedEvent()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        sendActivityStoppedEvent()
        super.onStop()
    }

    private fun sendActivityStartedEvent() {
        val params = Arguments.createMap()
        params.putBoolean("active", true)
        sendEvent("activityState", params)
    }

    private fun sendActivityStoppedEvent() {
        val params = Arguments.createMap()
        params.putBoolean("active", false)
        sendEvent("activityState", params)
    }

    private fun sendEvent(eventName: String, params: WritableMap?) {
        reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager.currentReactContext
                ?.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java)
                ?.emit(eventName, params)
    }
```

In order to access `reactNativeHost` your FullScreenActivity must be instance of ReactActivity

JS code:

```js
this.subscription = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('activityState', event => {
                     console.log(event.active)
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Adding on this: Is it possible to emit a react-native component from the full screen notification? if possible, then I don't have to maintain two kinds of the codebase. Rather I would develop everything in RN just with bridging the component in native. Let me know your thoughts

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I suppose you can open MainActivity from notification and process that notification in RN (I don't know if opening MainActivity consumes notification event), this needs testing

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a [native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) with two-way binding with:

- A function that RN calls on android, invoked every time the user change a react native screen
- When you receive a video notification, you check the current screen and decide if the `FullScreenActivity` should be shown or not
- [An event emitted by the native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript) every time the `FullScreenActivity` shows/hides, and react-native can subscribe to it

> when app is background or killed, FullScreenActivity should trigger.

I don't understand the question, You can't present/hide/do stuff when your app is killed

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you can use Actions.

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

Actions.currentScene;
```

Actions.currentScene gives you the active scene.

Comment: I have elaborated. Please re-check once.